# How to add a new image field in opencart

Tags: opencart2.x

Hello guys I want to add a new image field in `opencart2` on return product page

How can I add `image` field in opencart

I have done as far :

`view  : return_form.tpl`

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-comment1"><?php echo $entry_image; ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="file" name="error_img">
            </div>
          </div>
```

In controller `return.php` in function `add`

```
if (isset($this->request->post['error_img'])) {
            $data['error_img'] = $this->request->post['error_img'];
        } else {
            $data['error_img'] = false;
        }
```

but when I am trying to print the value of `$this->request->post['error_img']` it is returning blank

what I am missing

Comment: no default option available, need handy code, 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478995/how-to-become-an-opencart-guru

Comment: updated my code please help now

Comment: take this one is as reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28848952/send-attachment-in-php-with-opencart-2-1-1-1

Answer (score 0):

:)

you need to use `$this->request->files['error_img']` instead of `$this->request->post['error_img']`
in Opencart you can say

```
$_POST == $this->request->post;
$_GET == $this->request->get;
$_FILES == $this->request->files;
```

and many more. Please add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form too.