# Send Attachment in PHP with OpenCart 2.2.0.0

Tags: php, opencart2.x

Does anyone with knowledge of OpenCart 2.2.0.0 know how I could implement the `addAttachment` function found in `system/libary/mail.php`:

```
public function addAttachment($filename) {
    $this->attachments[] = $filename;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send Attachment in PHP with OpenCart 2.1.1.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28848952/send-attachment-in-php-with-opencart-2-1-1-1)